# HTML Table from JSON only showing 1 character per line

Tags: javascript, html, spring

I am trying to show a table that uses Json Data in an HTML table, but the table is only outputting one character per line. If I use a hard coded JSON object (edit: String not Object, cheers Chris) it works but if I use an object that has been pulled from the db (using spring) it only shows on character per line

[Screenshot of Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miz2n.png)

Thank you

```
var myList;
function getUser()
    {
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var theURL = "http://localhost:8080/user"
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
            {
             myList = (this.responseText);
             console.log(myList);
            }
        };
        xmlHttp.open("GET", theURL , true);
        xmlHttp.send();
    }
function tableFromJson()
{


    var col = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
        for (var key in myList[i]) {
            if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                col.push(key);
            }
        }
    }


    var table = document.createElement("table");


    var tr = table.insertRow(-1);

    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
        var th = document.createElement("th");
        th.innerHTML = col[i];
        tr.appendChild(th);
    }


    for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {

        tr = table.insertRow(-1);

        for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
            var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
            tabCell.innerHTML = myList[i][col[j]];
        }
    }


    var divShowData = document.getElementById('showData');
    divShowData.innerHTML = "";
    divShowData.appendChild(table);


}
```

Comment: The main problem I suspect is that you're using w3schools to learn javascript. There's no such thing as a "JSON object". Your `myList` is a *string*, and iterating over a string with a for loop yields its characters. You need to use `var tableData = JSON.parse(myList);` to parse the loaded JSON/text from the server into an actual array.

Comment: That worked, thank you